# Need help creating a simple console program that uses a header file I wrote

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, console-application, header-files

Im getting really depressed over this so I could really use some assistance.

I created a new project in visual studio. I first created a new header file, called "MyString,h" and placed it in the header folder. It contains a class called String. you can see the code I used for it at the end of this

I also now have a MyStringTest.cpp file in the source files folder. It has the following code in it.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "MyString.h"
    using namespace std;

    int main() {
            String obj = "Hello";
        cout << obj(1,3);
    }
```

Expected: Compiles and runs a console program which will output "llo"
Reality: Error: 'Identifier 'String' is undefined

Here is some of my code in the header file...i really cant fit all of it.

```
    //1. Preprocessor commands - guards against multiple inclusions of the file MyString.h
    #ifdef __MYSTRING_H__
    #define __MYSTRING_H_
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
    #define _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE

    //2. Include Files for String Methods and Assert
    #include<cstring> //strlen, strcpy, strcmp
    #include<cassert> //assert 
    #include<iostream> //cout, cin
    using namespace std;

    //3. Begin the String Class Interface
    class String{

    //4. Define the Public Members
    public:

        //5. Default Constructor
        String(); 

        //6. Constructor which converts a char* to a String object
        String(const char *s);
```

....

Comment: Identifiers starting with two underscores are reserved for the implementation. I use `MYSTRING_H`, and you'll see things like `MYSTRING_H_INCLUDED`. Identifiers starting with one underscore, followed by a capital letter are, too (both of these at least for any scope IIRC), but from the looks of it, the `_CRT*` stuff isn't yours, just good to know anyway.

Answer (score 2):

a little mistake at first code line: you need

```
#ifndef __MYSTRING_H__
```

otherwise you are *excluding* all of your file contents til `#endif`